# ExpireTimeSpan doesn't working in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project. I have used Identity 2.2.0 in my project. I have this code in `Startup.cs`:

```
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString")));
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

"ExpireTimeSpan" set to 10 days and the cookie expire date is true in the browser but after 10-20 minutes, the app asks to me log in again.
How do I increase time login?

Comment: Where do you host your web application?

Comment: @HadiSamadzad I host my web application in the IIS .

Comment: Are you using a server farm or a single server?

Comment: @HadiSamadzad I am using shared hosting.

Comment: @HadiSamadzad Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Which kind of browser are you using? Try to use different browser to check whether it works or not. Besides, based on your description, I also create a sample to check it, if set the `isPersistent` property to true, we can see the definite expired time, and it works well on my side. If the `isPersistent` property to false, the expired time is based on the session. So, please recheck the expired time in the Browser (using F12 developer tools Application tab), if the expired time is depend on the session, you could try to set the session expired time.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the mentioned shared hosting is on a server farm and you should define a key for the application as follow:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("./key"))            
    .SetApplicationName("SampleAppName")
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
```

This code should preserve the session status for 30 days.

Comment: It isn't working. When I want to log in, I'm getting error.